# Issue on single computer only - Conversion from string to type 'Date' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I regret having to write such a vague question, but I'm not really sure what to try. I have general programming experience, but no access to the source code for this and not a lot of experience with VB/.NET

We have a custom (Read: Crappy) CRM software we use at work that was written ~2008 by someone who has long since left the company. It works on both Windows 7 and Windows 10 just fine for multiple users. I am trying help a user with an "Unexpected program error":

"frmMain - FillGridTable
Conversion from string "03/31/2016 15:23:22" to type 'Date' is not valid."

when I close the dialog box it just says "LoopX = 0"

I do not have access to the source code, and regardless, it works on every other computer.

Could this be some issue with some type of library on the computer? Is there any way to check versions between computers for .NET/Microsoft libraries?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Does the computer have different regional settings with a different date format?

Comment: DING-FREAKING-DING. Thanks man. Now I feel stupid, but at least the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Chase Rocker helped me get here in the comment he left on the question.

The windows date/time format settings were displaying a date that wasn't in the correct format. Resolved this by changing it to the MM/dd/YYYY format the error was suggesting the program expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad to see that you solved the issue by changing the computer's regional settings, but to be honest this is probably overkill for what you're wanting to do. Instead, you could have used the [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

Here is a quick example of utilizing the built-in method:

```
Dim conversion As DateTime
Dim input As String = "11/30/2017"

If DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "MM/dd/yyyy", New CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, conversion) Then
    'Converted successfully
Else
    'A true conversion error occured
End If
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cb2IhZ)

Comment: Fine, but the OP explicitly said no access to source